# ImageButton onClick change color

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm creating an ImageButton like so:

```
          <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.333"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_one"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@drawable/dialpad_1" />
```

I would like to implement a way to have the button flash or change color when clicked/pressed just to identify that it as been clicked. I know I can reference the background as a drawable with a selector of state_pressed to a certain color. I'm trying to avoid making a separate xml file for each button in the drawable. What's the best way of doing this without creating all those extra xml files?

Comment: in that case don't set any background color it will work naturally..

Comment: Or on click change color of button..

Comment: What exactly do you mean don't set a background color? I have @null now.

Comment: means no background color and android provide default color on click any button..
and it feel you you have pres someting or use selector as you know..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create custom drawable selectors for your button background.

This file will live in your XML folder, and look something like this (each element describes the button background when in different selected states):

File would be named: res/drawable/my_custom_selector.xml

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_on"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_on"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_off"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_off"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Then to apply that background to your ImageView (or any View), just set it as the background:

```
 <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.333"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/my_custom_selector"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_button_one"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@drawable/dialpad_1" />
```

Comment: Got it. So if I have 12 buttons I need to create 12 xml files?

Comment: No, the same background can be used in all your buttons.  ie. just apply the same background to each of your buttons (and they will all be the same look when pressed). button1.setBackground(my_drawable); button2.setBackground(my_drawable); etc

Answer (score 1):

The XML files you are trying to avoid is the easy way to achieve what you want.
The other way would be the do it using code in the `onClickListener`, which in my opinion is a task that needs much more work.

Comment: Since there is a different src for each button, I have to create a separate xml for every button, correct?

Comment: Indeed, but the alternative is that you will have to specify a different texture for pressed and unpressed state using code, which is even worse. So I think you should go that way.

Comment: Didn't I answer you question?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to implement the other answer and see if it works.

Comment: what is the other answer? the selector suggested by Booger?

Answer (score -1):

**You should XML files or else don't do anything.Android provides default color for the button pressed.**